# set keep_logical_logs in embedded Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I need to get rid of logical logs of `Neo4j` as they eat up to whole RAM disk. My graph is very huge. I define `Neo4j 3.0.6` database embedded in Java, like :

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(new File(PATH + GRAPH_DATABASE_PATH)).setConfig("keep_logical_logs","false").newGraphDatabase();
```

I also set keep_logical_logs to "4 files", "`100M size`", but it insist to keep 100 of them ( *neostore.transaction.db.0 to 99*) each of size 251M !!!
I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Mattias, but it was just a silly mistake I made. I needed to remove the quotes of keep_logical_logs and import : org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseSettings.keep_logical_logs

Answer (score 0):

As it currently stands, Neo4j cannot prune logs beyond the last checkpoint. Try to lower checkpoint interval () and you'll see that logs can be pruned more aggressively.

I.e. lower dbms.checkpoint.interval.tx and dbms.checkpoint.interval.time. That should help.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this?
eg, how is that value set?